# How do I reload the app when a notification arrives React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a notification listener, and I need the app to refresh when a specific notification arrives. How do I make the screen reload/refresh in react native?

For more context, my app has two types of users, anons and friends. When I send out a friend request to an anon, and they approve, I need to the screen to refetch users so that they are removed from anon list and added to the friend list.

A potential solution would be to dispatch a user fetch in the App.js where notification listeners are, but I wonder if it's slightly easier/cleaner or even possible to just cause a screen refresh (rerender) in react native.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just fetch again the anons and friends list to update the lists ?